# What file format for should i use for storing data packets together?

Tags: php

I have a advance cache system I use, and I store the results of a packet encoding inside a .dat file.

Example:

```
public function saveChunk($pk, $id){
    file_put_contents("cache/" . $id, serialize($pk));
}
```

This creates a .dat file which has the chunk encoding.

Anyways, this creates about 7000 .dat files, and it is very messy on my linux server.

Whats a good way I can have **one file** and assign a ID to each packet, and later retrieve the packet with the id? (It also needs to be speed efficient)

Comment: If you want speed, use a database or a key/value store. Else, you will have to load the entire file into memory, parse it, replace/add/remove whatever you want and dump that entire file back to disk. All of that on every single request to the page. Which will be anything but "efficient". You might be able to make it a little better for multiple writes in the same request by using static variables in the function (load once on first call) or a class with a destructor (write to disk once at the end of the request), but still not ideal.